# Write unmapped characters to file?

Tags: python, encoding, output

For example: the character \x80, or 128 in decimal, has no UTF-8 character assigned to it. But if I understand text files correctly, I should still be able to create a file that contains that character, even if nothing can display it. However, when I try to print an array that contains one of these characters, it writes as '\x80', and when I try to write it directly as a chr, I get an error "UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x80' in position 0: character maps to ". Am I doing something fundamentally wrong, or is there a fix I just don't know about here?

Comment: uh just use binary type, text files need to have character mapping

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what that means

Comment: `with open("binchars.txt", "wb") as f: f.write(b"\x80")`

Comment: What do you mean with "UTF-8 character"? UTF-8 is an encoding, not a set of characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bytes type in Python is what I should have been using for this. Though I didn't quite understand it when I was posting the question, I needed a list of single-byte variables. This is exactly what the bytes object does, and even better, it can be used exactly like a string.